# php $_SESSION not sent through login.php file

Tags: php, session, windows-xp, xampp

I have created my site on windows xp32 and a few days ago. Then re installed the same type of windows (professional xp 32bit).

Now my website does not work properly. `$_SESSIONS` are not sent and I wonder if the windows have something to do with this (cuz i turned off some start-up services in `msconfig->services`).
Other thing i suspect is the `XAMPP`. After I found out the problem I edited `php.ini` in Apache 1000times and it did not fix the problem. 
In Google a lot of people complain about common problem. They say that they changed server and now sessions are not sent.

I am new to php and do not have idea what exactly is going on.

Can someone help me with some hints about where might the problem be and also I would like to know if it is a good practice to use alternatives of sessions, for example if user is `logged_in()->send` data to `mysql-> SET logged_in = 1;` and if l`ogout() -> SET logged_in = 0`.
Or anything else.
Every info on this matter would be helpful. Thank you!

here is the exact code situation:
project link: http://dox.bg/files/dw?a=e2f056d0f2
I have this login form:

```
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="username">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="password" name="password">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="login">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="register.php">register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>    
        </form>
```

in login.php I have this:

```
...
    else 
                    {  
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
                    //... $_SESSION['user_id'] works here and outputs the correct data - user_id
                    header('Location: index.php');
                    exit();
...
```

and in int.php(it is incl in `index.php`) I have this:

```
session_start();

print_r(session_get_cookie_params()); echo '<br>'; // outputs: Array ( [lifetime] => 0 [path] => / [domain] => [secure] => [httponly] => ) 
print_r(session_status());  echo '<br>'; // output: 2

var_dump($_SESSION); // output: array(0) { } 
print_r($_SESSION);
print_r($_SESSION['user_id']); // outputs: "Notice: Undefined index: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\orderfood\Core\int.php on line 10"

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
require 'functions/options.php';

if(logged_in() === true)//this is ok.
{

$session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];  // <-------- not working...
```

... script continues

**Fixed.** I cannot explain exactly what was wrong but I removed `session_start()` from `core/int.php` (by the way, the path was written without 'core/') and I added `session_start()` in my `index.php` and in the files that require logged in users.

This fixed the issue for me. Actualy this is appears to be a noobish mistake. I had the website running in the previous windows but I accidentally deleted it and the files i provided in the ink are from an old back-up, which I believed has been working but that was not true.. Sorry for noob post and thank you for your attention.

Comment: just edited this and I have no change.

Comment: @RishiKalia that is not true, `session_start()` must not be called more than once per request.

Comment: thank you for your comments! Note that this same script was working ok on my previous windows xp configoration. after reinstall sessions stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `session_start()` in all the files. Moreover, don't use `session_close()` or `session_destroy()`, because it clears all the session variables.

The issue comes when you redirect. So, check both `login.php` and `index.php` to have `session_start()` in the beginning.

It would be easy to debug, if you give the full source code of the PHP files.

---

#### After seeing the files:

You have added this line:

```
include '/core/int.php';
```

In all the files, this should be replaced with:

```
include 'core/int.php';
```

It is because, this is not a linux machine and morever, you have give relative paths here or absolute path from `C:\XAMPP\`, etc. Hope this fixes the issue.

Comment: session_start() is included in my inc.php file which is included everywhere. I use session_destroy only in logout.php file when logout is clicked.  The script was working fine before i reinstalled windows and xampp.  i wonder if the syntax have something to do with the problem also. for example on the old windows I had to use different quoting for sending data to MYsql.

Comment: Hey, why don't you check in a different browser? Normal mode, if on Private / Incognito mode. Some way?

Comment: no change on safari and iexplorer. cookies are on, standard mode

Comment: Seriously, challenging question. Update your question, if it is fine to put your source code, update it in the question, even if it is too long. Lemme go thru. :) Will surely fix it.

Comment: sorry. this does not work here. thank you for your effort, though :))

Answer (score 0):

A solution would have been to declare `ini_set(' session.save_path','SOME WRITABLE PATH');` in all your script files but that would have been a pain.